# Sketch Toolbox doesn't work ? Frozen Blank Screen

Tags: macos, plugins

I am using Sketch version 3.7 and Sketch Toolbox.

The first week I had sketch toolbox, it worked but now I have a blank frozen user interface. I tried to unistall and reinstall but that didn't work.

Anyone have a solution to this ?

Comment: I wasn't able to find much information about the version on their website or their github. I was curious if 3.7 is a beta or stable release?